# Docker on remote and intellij

Tags: docker, intellij-idea, docker-compose

So long story short:
1. I have VM running on `VMware Workstation player`
2. I have docker installed on VM, and 2375 port for docker socket avaliable
3. I have docker-compose on my host `IntelliJ` I would like to run on docker

I had to remove `Hyper-V` features on my host so I am trying to use docker on VM but whenever I try to run docker compose I get:

> Failed to deploy 'Compose: docker-compose-utils.yml':
>   com.intellij.execution.process.ProcessNotCreatedException: Cannot run
>   program "docker-compose" (in directory
>   "C:\Users\mith\IdeaProjects\mixer"): CreateProcess error=2, Nie
>   można odnaleźć określonego plik

I cant run `Docker Desktop` cause it require `Hyper-V` features enabled which will make my VMplayer to crush.

Is it possible to somehow use docker features on vm via intellij ?

Comment: Does it run fine from command line?

Comment: Same situation for me, but I use Vbox and cannot install Hyper-V. I was looking for a solution and I found your question a bit later.
I resolved as i write in the answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Step 1**

Download the compose executable from the [official repository](https://github.com/docker/compose/releases), rename it as `docker-compose`( optional ).
It's a stand alone executable, you don't need docker installed ( see step 3 )

**Step 2**

From the IntelliJ setting, choose *Build, Execution, Deployment* `->` *Docker* `->` *Tools* `->` *Docker Compose executable* and paste the path and the name of the downloaded file
( `C:\Users\marco\AppData\Local\Docker\docker-compose.exe` )

**Step 3**

Edit the *Run/Debug Configurations* for the compose entry and in the *Environment variables* write the host address for the `DOCKER_HOST` variable, e.g `DOCKER_HOST=192.168.0.100:2375`

Now you can run this configuration with `shift+F10`